# Geoserver caching with SQL view

Tags: geoserver, google-maps, geowebcache

In Geoserver I have a layer based on SQL view. I enabled WMS direct integration in GeoWebcache and I enabled caching in layer.

In Google Maps javascript API I add a layer in this way. Layer is projected, but caching not happens:

```
var wmsLayer =
new google.maps.ImageMapType({
getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {

    var s = Math.pow(2, zoom);
    var twidth = 256;
    var theight = 256;

    //define boundingbox
    var gBl = cmap.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(
        new google.maps.Point(coord.x * twidth / s, (coord.y + 1) * theight / s)); //zuidwest coördinaat
    var gTr = cmap.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(
        new google.maps.Point((coord.x + 1) * twidth / s, coord.y * theight / s)); //noordoost coördinaat

    var bbox = gBl.lng() + "," + gBl.lat() + "," + gTr.lng() + "," + gTr.lat();

    //basics WMS URL
    var url = "http://geoserver.xxx.be/geoserver/rcs/wms?";

    url += "&service=WMS";
    url += "&version=1.1.0";
    url += "&request=GetMap";
    url += "&layers=rcs:rcs-sql-server-source-with-parameters-public";
    url += "&styles=";
    url += "&format=image/png";
    url += "&TRANSPARENT=TRUE";
    url += "&srs=EPSG:4326";
    url += "&bbox=" + bbox;
    url += "&width=256";
    url += "&height=256";
    url += "&customheader=" + new Date().getTime();
    url += "&viewparams=kind:bike;groupid:1";
    url += "&tiled=true";

    return url;
},

tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
opacity: 0.85,
isPng: true
});
```

Comment: Does it create cache if you use the demo viewer from /geoserver/gwc?

Comment: Yes, then cache is created. But demo doesn't use viewparams, only default parameters. So when I don't add viewparams parameter to wms URL, cache is created. I use GeoServer 2.10, maybe I have to upgrade to 2.11?

Comment: Would it make sense to create cache with view parameters? Then you would need a separate cache for each parameter combination. But I can't say what GeoServer is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the viewparams as a "parameter filter" in the tile cache description and provide an indication of which combinations will be cached, because indeed, each combination generates a separate tile cache.

See the documentation here:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/webadmin/layers.html#parameter-filters